# How to apply Time.timeScale only to certain scripts?

Tags: unity, 2d, camera, time, deltatime

I have a need to pause my game and the simplest and most clean way that I know of (other than completely designing my own time system) is by using `Time.timeScale = 0;`

However, this also makes my CameraController script stop working, because it relies on `LateUpdate()` and `FixedUpdate()` to update the camera position.

How would I change the timescale for other things that rely on it, but leave the part of it that the CameraController works with intact?

My first thought was adding a variable `int isPaused;` to parts of code that need to be stopped, and then instead of actually setting the timeScale to 0, I'd just change that isPaused variable to zero, and then multiply it with Time.deltaTime as usual, which would result in that object not moving, while still keeping my CameraController working. However, I'm not sure if this is the cleanest and simplest way to achieve something like this. Perhaps designing my own time system would be more beneficial in the long run?

Here's the CameraController code incase it is needed: https://hatebin.com/fqtybcuwht

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with what you've suggested. I would use another `float` value - just like `Time.timeScale` itself - which is set to either `0.0f` or `1.0f`, to multiply by in all scripts except your `CameraController`. It becomes `0.0f` when you pause, `1.0f` otherwise.

This way, you also avoid conditionals - multiplication is cheaper than checking `if (someFlag) ...`